# Average calculator - Why doesn't "var += var;" nested in a while loop work?

Tags: c, variables, average

I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow as well as C programming, hope I don't annoy anyone with lack of knowledge.

I'm creating an average calculator for Kickstarter projects, what I was wondering is why the method below doesn't work. Not the average but why backers and money come out doubled if you were to enter 1 backer and $10 pledged each day,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main(void){

    int loopcount = 0;
    int backers = 0;
    int money = 0;
    int average = 0;

    int tbackers = 0;
    int tmoney = 0;

    while(loopcount<5){

       //Ask for # of backers and total money pledged.
       printf("Please Enter the number of backers today, then the total money pledged                                today:\n");
       scanf("%d\n%d", &backers, &money);

       //
       backers += backers;
       money += money;


       loopcount++;
        }
       //average = tmoney / tbackers;
       printf("There were %d backers and the total collected was $%d.\nSo the average amount pledged was  $%d", backers, money, average);

       getch();

}
```

but the following works fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){

    int loopcount = 0;
    int backers = 0;
    int money = 0;
    int average = 0;

    int tbackers = 0;
    int tmoney = 0;

    while(loopcount<5){

       //Ask for # of backers and total money pledged.
       printf("Please Enter the number of backers today, then the total money pledged today:\n");
       scanf("%d\n%d", &backers, &money);

       //
       tbackers += backers;
       tmoney += money;


       loopcount++;
    }
       //average = tmoney / tbackers;
       printf("There were %d backers and the total collected was $%d.\nSo the average amount pledged was  $%d", tbackers, tmoney, average);

       getch();

}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `backers += backers;` What do you think it does?

Comment: Why are you just making an average calculator? Wouldn't it be better to make a *great* calculator?

Comment: @CodyGray Every journey, no matter how great, starts with but one step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, after each calculation, you override the value when you get a new user input:

```
scanf("%d\n%d", &backers, &money);
```

For example:

```
line                  | backers    | money
----------------------+------------+------
user input 5 3        | 5          | 3
backers += backers    | 10         | 3
money += money        | 10         | 6
user input 8 6        | 8          | 6
backers += backers    | 16         | 6
money += money        | 16         | 12
```

Now, in the second example, you don't override the values, but add them to the sum:

```
line                  | backers    | money    | tbackers   | tmoney    
----------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------
user input 5 3        | 5          | 3        | 0          | 0
tbackers += backers   | 5          | 3        | 5          | 0
tmoney += money       | 5          | 3        | 5          | 3
user input 8 6        | 8          | 6        | 5          | 3
tbackers += backers   | 8          | 6        | 13         | 3
tmoney += money       | 8          | 6        | 13         | 9
```

Answer (score 1):

What does "doesn't work" exactly mean?  I cannot imagine it doesn't work.

`money += money` adds the value of `money` to the content of variable `money`, effectively doubling its value.

If you want to achieve something else, you have to express something else, as you do in your 2nd example: have a variable for the total sum and one for the user input. If you mix them up, you end up in destroyed (overwritten) data.

If you are in C99 or your compiler allows it otherwise, you could declare your variables close to where you need them:

[...]

```
while(loopcount<5){
   int money = 0;
   int average = 0;


   //Ask for # of backers and total money pledged.
   printf("Please Enter the number of backers today, then the total money pledged today:\n");
   scanf("%d\n%d", &backers, &money);

   //
   tbackers += backers;
   tmoney += money;

   loopcount++;
}
[...]
```

This restricts the use of `backers` and `money` to the range of the `while` loop, so they cannot leak out.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Yes, but this is one thing the OP should understand too before they can get their program working.

Comment: Not enough +rep otherwise I would upvote this aswell, I see what you're conveying about using the local scope of variables.

Comment: @glglgl - although not the first problem, this is a catch as well, my previous comment was regarding "I cannot imagine it doesn't work".